# default_wait_time for Intern Selenium tests

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, requirejs, selenium-chromedriver, intern

Is there an equivalent to Capybara's (RoR) default_wait_time for the Intern?

setPageLoadTimeout and setFindTimeout don't seem to accomplish anything.

this.timeout = 60000 seems to give an entire test 60 seconds, but I want all steps to have a default wait time. Otherwise it feels the steps are running out of order because elements that steps rely on are not yet on the page.

```
        var title = 'title ' + (new Date()).toString();
        var remote = this.remote;
        return remote
            .get(require.toUrl('http://' + Configs.host + '/logout'))
            .get(require.toUrl('http://' + Configs.host + '/auth/facebook'))
            .findById('email')
                .click()
                .type(Configs.fb.username)
                .end()
            .findById('pass')
                .click()
                .type(Configs.fb.password)
                .end()
            .findByCssSelector('#login_form input[type=submit]')
                .click()
                .end()
            // browser successfully navigates to "/things"
            .findByCssSelector('a.new_thing')
                .click()
                .end()
        // browser often navigates to "/things/new"
            .findByCssSelector('input.title')
        // terminal message always 'StaleElementReference'
        // even though a pollUntil (ommitted) does find 'input.title'
                .click()
                .type(title)
                .end()
            .findByCssSelector('button.create')
                .click()
                .end()
```

Does anyone else use this framework reliably for a single page web app?

Comment: Could you please show some code, like the test case you are writing? `setFindTimeout` is definitely the same thing.

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample of the test code. I have comments in the code. I'm using html5 pushState, the browser address bar navigates to complete URLs, but they are actually just mappings to client side Backbone.js router paths.

Answer (score 0):

[`setFindTimeout`](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setFindTimeout) sets the amount of time the remote server will wait for an element to appear when attempting to find an element before timing out. If elements aren’t guaranteed to exist on the page immediately, then you should call `setFindTimeout` after loading the page:

```
return this.remote.get('http://example.com')
  .setFindTimeout(5000)
  .findById('email')
    .click()
    .type(Configs.fb.username)
    .end()
  .findById('pass')
    .click()
    .type(Configs.fb.password)
    .end()
  // ...
```

Note that some Selenium servers will reset the wait timeout after loading a new page, so you may need to call it again when a new page is loaded.

Comment: I added it where you suggest, but it doesn't work. Where my test is breaking is after  findByCssSelector('a.new_thing').click().end(). I get 'StaleElementReference' even though a pollUntil, calling document.getQuerySelector('input.thing') gets an element, and I can see the input field on the browser.

Comment: Actually, I think that it's because I'm doing a .html('') within my code to wipe out a section of content, and the runner code has an old reference to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/4309cf4b-8005-4caf-a5c3-dd3d0d20e237/element/12/click which no longer exists as element 12, because the previous elements were wiped.

Comment: would be nice if there were a retry after n*1000 ms.

Comment: .sleep() seems to help a lot.